# SPFx Form Customizer Deployment issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx, list-form, spfx-extensions

I built SPFx Form Customizer but I have problems when I deploy it. It doesn't get applied to forms. I assume that the issue is in connecting form customizer with list.

I tried following several instructions but nothing worked. Is there an full instruction guide from start to end of deployment for Form Customizer, or if someone can write steps? Or at least on how to connect form customizer with list, but more detailed
What should I check?

Is it only needed to create form extension & code for it, add relevant information in `serve.json` and deploy app to app catalog, what am I missing?

I should be able to see my custom for when myList/EditForm.aspx, myList/NewForm.aspx and myList/DispForm.aspx is opened, is that correct?

Comment: After deploying and installing SPFx extension, you have to associate the custom form component to the content type. Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1I0uE-IiLEM) and [article](https://www.voitanos.io/blog/sharepoint-framework-register-list-form-customizers-rest-api/) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deploying SPFx form customizer extension to app catalog and then installing it your SharePoint site, you have to associate the custom form customizer to the content type using the specific properties in `ContentType` object.

There are few options to do this:

- You can provision the used list and content type from your solution if you are using site scoped deployment option
- You can associate the component to content types using REST or CSOM APIs.

There is a SPFx web part developed by community members which will help you to associate and/or remove association of the list form customizer extension to a particular list. Check the SPFx web part sample at: [Add Form Customizer to List](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-add-formcustomizer-to-list)

For detailed information about how to use this SPFx web part and SharePoint REST APIs to associate SPFx form customizer to SharePoint lists, check below links:

1. [Add form customizers to a list SPFx web part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1I0uE-IiLEM)
2. [Register SPFx list form customizers with the SharePoint REST API](https://www.voitanos.io/blog/sharepoint-framework-register-list-form-customizers-rest-api/)